# Using NGINX to proxy external connections to look internal

Tags: nginx, proxy

Sorry if the question is unclear, but I have something like

```
server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
  }
}
```

I can go to server.com and it works, but I want to make it look to the internal server (127.0.0.1:3000) like I'm connecting from an address inside the network. I would think there should be some way to establish a connection from within the server and pass the data back out, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: This seems to do already what you want. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "to make it look to the internal server like I'm connecting from an address inside the network.". Where exactly in the internal server are you looking at?

Comment: I want it to look to the internal :3000 server like the request originated in the machine that  runs the NGINX reverse proxy. Specifically ,I just want it to look like a request that was made by a machine on the same local network, but the easiest way I assumed to do it was that.